# get value of select option every time for every lines

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let customer of in_task_only">
  <ion-col col-10>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <h1>{{customer.lsl_contact_person}} SC_L: {{customer.lsl_sys_id }} </h1>
        <h2>Contact No : {{customer.lsl_contact_no}} 
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-2>
    <h5> {{customer.lsl_job_status}} </h5>
    Change Status
    <select  (change)="changeStatus(value,{{customer.lsl_sys_id }})" >
      <option value="reschedule"> Re-schedule </option>
      <option value="completed"> Completed </option>
    </select>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I want to get select value for each line in `'changeStatus(value,{{customer.lsl_sys_id }})'`  select is dynamic on the basis of customer rows.

controler code `

```
 in_task_only :any;
      status : any;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.in_task_only=this.navParams.get('in_task_only');
        console.log('measuremet in_task_only',this.in_task_only);
      }

  changeStatus(status,id ){
    console.log(status , id);
  }`
```

how to get select option status??

Comment: Please post your component

Comment: posted now please check

Comment: when do you want the select option status when the status changes everytime?

Comment: when ever user changes the status of the line i want to get that with line id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing why are you not using ion-select tag which ionic has inbuilt as you are developing an ionic app it would be better if you use ionic specific tags unless you require something out of the box which ionic doesn't provide.

Second thing if you want to pass any specific value from your ngFor there is no need to pass interpolation inside the function parameters you can simply pass the value without {{}}

try this with ion-select tag in your html:

```
<ion-select  (ionChange)="changeStatus($event,customer.lsl_sys_id)" >
  <ion-option value="reschedule"> Re-schedule </ion-option>
  <ion-option value="completed"> Completed </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

you can even use ngModel on the ion-select and get the selected value just by passing the model name:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="newstate" (ionChange)="changeStatus(newstate,customer.lsl_sys_id)" > // you can even assign a new property on the customer if you want use ngModel name as customer.newProp
  <ion-option value="reschedule"> Re-schedule </ion-option>
  <ion-option value="completed"> Completed </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

and in your ts:

```
changeStatus(status,id ){
  console.log(status , id); // you will get the value as well as the relative item id here 
}
```

Comment: Actully i was testing other option bcse  when i select <ion-option> value it was not showing complete test. Like if i select "Re-schdule"  then it will display "Re-" , how to display full status text.